# Ajax.Request to external site: XSS or not?

Tags: javascript, xss, prototypejs

I thought the below was not working because I was attempting XSS, but I tried performing a local port redirect to confirm, and it still wouldn't work. Can someone let me know if this is XSS or not, and if not, why it's not working?

```
<html>
   <div id="output"></div>
   <script src="prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function test()
      {
         this.url = "http://www.google.com"
      }

      test.prototype.run = function() 
      {
         var request = new Ajax.Request(this.url, 
            {
               method: "get",
               onSuccess: this.success.bind(this),
               onFailure: function(response) { alert("failure"); }
            });
      };

      test.prototype.success = function(response)
      {
         var debug = "this.url = " + this.url + ",<br>"
            + " response.status = " + response.status + ",<br>"
            + " response.statusText = " + response.statusText + ",<br>"
            + " response.readyState = " + response.readyState + ",<br>"
            + " response.responseText = " + response.responseText + ",<br>"
            + " response.responseXML = " + response.responseXML + ",<br>"
            + " response.responseJSON = " + response.responseJSON + ",<br>"
            + " response.headerJSON = " + response.headerJSON + ",<br>"
            + " response.request = " + response.request + ",<br>"
            + " response.transport = " + response.transport + ",<br>"
            + " response.transport.readyState = " + response.transport.readyState + ",<br>"
            + " response.transport.responseText = " + response.transport.responseText + ",<br>";
         document.getElementById("output").update(debug);
      };

      new test().run();
   </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's not XSS (which is a way to attack the client side of web applications), but it is simply the same origin policy being in effect here. You can't simply request data with an Ajax request from a domain other than your own (your own meaning the one your web application was loaded from).

Learn more about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Exactly. XSS is an attack. The same origin policy is there to prevent these kinds of attack. Otherwise a site could simply load your data from gmail or any other site and steal the information. If you want to load data from an external site from Ajax, use a proxy on you website, and load the data through the proxy.